Maintaining Parameters Across Page Redirections in Playwright Automation
Is it feasible to consistently append parameters to URLs in Playwright automation, ensuring they persist through redirects and subsequent page transitions?
When initiating automation with a URL like www.example.com?param=test, the webpage redirects to www.example.com/auth/login, subsequently dropping the parameter value. This behavior prompts the need for a method to retain parameters even through such redirections. Additionally, any subsequent page transitions triggered by user interactions should preserve these appended parameters.
I tried request interception, but it append the parameter to the network requests, not to the application URL

Why do you want to do this? The purpose of Playwright is to test the application as it naturally works, not to force it into unnatural states it can't achieve on its own, because that's an unrealistic test. Is there user visible behavior you can test? Please provide more details about your use case, if only to motivate why it's necessary to do this. Thanks.
